# Why GetProcesses() doesn't show all of running processes

Tags: c#, winforms, taskmanager

when I run the following code, I expect to get the name of all processes running in the system, but in some other PCs than mine, there is a running process that is visible in the TaskManager but my app doesn't show it, I wanna know if I'm doing something wrong or there is any way to solve this, BTW my app is running as Administrator so that's not the problem. Thanks for your help.

```
foreach(Process Proc in Process.GetProcesses()) {
    T += Proc.ProcessName + ", ";
}
```

Comment: Do you know the names of those processes not listed by _GetProcesses()_

Comment: You could compare the list or processes returned by [Win32_Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) and [Win32_Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service) (or [ServiceController.GetServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices)) and see whether what you think is missing is in any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple OS services can be loaded within the same instance of the Service Host process (svchost.exe). `GetProcesses` does not identify those individual services; for that, use [GetServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices?view=netframework-4.8). Be sure to read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Process.GetProcesses() does not return system processes. Services may also appear as svhost.exe.